# Debugging a std::set issue

Tags: c++, stl, set

I wrote a set with special ordering:

```
std::set<int,std::function<bool(int const&,int const&)>> ListCases;
```

and I have problems with it. I cannot remove a value 9 from it because a call to

```
ListCases.find(9);
```

does not return a dereferencable iterator.
But when I print all the values of that set with following loop:

```
for (auto & eVal : ListCases)
  std::cerr << " " << eVal;
```

I can see that the value 9 is in the list of values stored.

The bug disappear when I isolate the code in a separate program. Running clang++ with compiler option -fsanitize=undefined and other checks did not return anything.

What are the possible explanations for this? What other debugging option can be considered?

Comment: What `does not return a dereferencable iterator` means?

Comment: Is your actual code initialising the set with an actual function? Otherwise, all bets are pretty much off.

Comment: Having a complete example program would help here. A *guess* would be that your comparison function is not doing it's job correctly - you need to impose a strict weak ordering on the keys (ints).   What does the comparison function do?

Comment: A non dereferencable iterator is an iterator such as ListCases.end().

Comment: I solved my problem. The issue was with the compare function which was broken. Was there a way to detect that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the Compare function?

Using this piece of code

```
typedef std::set<int,std::function<bool(int const&,int const&)>> MySet;

MySet wListCases([](int l, int r){ return l<r; });

wListCases.insert(9);
wListCases.insert(88);
wListCases.insert(1);

auto found = wListCases.find(9);

for (auto & eVal : wListCases)
  std::cout << " " << eVal << std::endl;
```

If I do not provide the function with the lambda `[](int l, int r){ return l<r; }` this program will crash. Otherwise, it will find 9 and print `1, 9, 88`